# How to create an on and off listener for a function

Tags: javascript, events

I have a function lets say for simplicity I have the following Pub/Sub pattern:

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qvbs4gy6/)

```js
const Controller = function() {
  const listeners = {};

  this.on = (event, fn) => {
    listeners[event] = listeners[event] || [];
    listeners[event].push(fn);
  };

  this.off = (event, fn) => {
    if (listeners[event]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < listeners[event].length; i++) {
        if (listeners[event][i] === fn) {
          listeners[event].splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(listeners);
  };

  this.triggerListeners = (event, data) => {
    if (listeners[event]) {
      listeners[event].forEach((fn) => {
        fn(data);
      });
    }
  };
}

const ctl = new Controller();

ctl.on('click', () => console.log('foo'));

ctl.on('click', () => console.log('bar'));

document.querySelector('.trigger').addEventListener('click', () => {
 ctl.triggerListeners('click', 'some data');
})

document.querySelector('.remove').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ctl.off('click', () => console.log('bar'));
})
```

```html
<button class="trigger">
Trigger Listeners
</button>

<button class="remove">
Click to remove listener
</button>
```

I am having issues removing functions on account of not being able to find the function in the array because the are not `===`.

If i click the button I would like to be able to remove the `console.log('bar')` function from the list.

Comment: you just need a ref to the on-passed function.

Comment: Look at this gist. https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/777349747d8382bfb722

Comment: The function that you passed in the `.on()` method does not have the same reference as the function you passed in the `.off()` method. Store the function that you passed in the `on()` method in a separate variable, pass it in the `.on()` and `.off()` method. You should get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in the comments above, the function that you've passed in the `.on()` method does not have the same reference as the function that you've passed in the `.off()` method.

You can try to perform this operation and you'll see what I meant:

```js
console.log(
  (() => console.log('log')) === (() => console.log('log'))
);
```

The operation above should return false.

> In JavaScript, objects are a reference type. Two distinct objects are never equal, even if they have the same properties. Only comparing the same object reference with itself yields true.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_objects

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Since functions are reference types then two distinctly created functions cannot be the same.

To solve your problem then you only need to store the function that you've passed in the `.on()` method and use such function to be passed in the `.off()` method.

```
const ctl = new Controller();

const onBar = () => console.log('bar');

ctl.on('click', onBar);

ctl.off('click', onBar);
```

```js
const Controller = function() {
  const listeners = {};

  this.on = (event, fn) => {
    listeners[event] = listeners[event] || [];
    listeners[event].push(fn);
  };

  this.off = (event, fn) => {
    if (listeners[event]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < listeners[event].length; i++) {
        if (listeners[event][i] === fn) {
          listeners[event].splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(listeners);
  };

  this.triggerListeners = (event, data) => {
    if (listeners[event]) {
      listeners[event].forEach((fn) => {
        fn(data);
      });
    }
  };
}

const ctl = new Controller();

const onBar = () => console.log('bar');

ctl.on('click', onBar);

ctl.off('click', onBar);
```